# Close Publisher in VF Quick Action in Aloha

Tags: visualforce, canvas, publisher-action

I've written an object-specific quick action which works wonderfully in Lightning Experience and in SF1. It also works in Aloha, but the final piece is to have the publisher close itself when the save completes successfully.

This Javascript code works to close the publisher in SF1 and LEX:

```
Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({
    name: "publisher.close",
    payload: { refresh: "true", successMessage: 'Success!' }
});
```

In Aloha, nothing happens when this code is run. Are there any workarounds to get the publisher to close?

Comment: Since the publisher action creates a new record, my temporary fix is to send the user to the new record by setting `window.parent.location.href`.